# Slow on COLLECT in Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a Cypher that returns a "combined limit" on two set of results, one is immediate neighbors, the other is neighbors cross "event nodes", as following:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject:Person {age:"38"})--(event:Event)--(targetViaEvent)   
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject)--(directTarget)  
  WHERE NOT directTarget:Event  
WITH subject, targetViaEvent, directTarget,  
  COUNT(event) AS eventCount 
  ORDER BY eventCount DESC  
WITH subject, COLLECT(directTarget) + COLLECT(targetViaEvent) as targetList  
UNWIND targetList AS target  
WITH DISTINCT subject, target 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
...
```

The main purpose of this Cypher query is:

1. Find all the neighbors
2. If a neighbor is labeled `Event`, find the other neighbors of the event
3. Sort the event-connected-neighbor by the amount of events
4. Return neighbors found above, whether labeled `Event` or not, use skip and limit for pagination 
   4.1. If capable, return neighbors with `Event` label ahead over the ones without

Other specifications:

1. All relationship types and directions are taking account, so these are not filtered

With `COLLECT()` used, the execution time gets unbelievably slow, making neo4j shell stall, as each *subject* may have ten thousands of `directTarget` and `targetViaEvent`. I suspect `COLLECT()` caches every matched node object in memory, thus jams Neo4j in this data scale. My intention is just to combine the two, and do limitation altogether. Is there any tricks to improve my Cypher?

---

EDIT:

As @InverseFalcon pointed out my mistake in my Cypher above, here's my entire Cypher with updates:

```
PROFILE MATCH (subject:Person {age:"38"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject)--(directTarget)
  WHERE NOT directTarget:Event
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject)--(event:Event)--(targetViaEvent)
WITH subject, targetViaEvent, directTarget,
     COUNT(event) AS eventCount ORDER BY eventCount DESC
WITH subject, COLLECT(directTarget) + COLLECT(targetViaEvent) as targetList
UNWIND targetList AS target
WITH DISTINCT subject, target SKIP 0 LIMIT 300 WHERE target IS NOT NULL
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject)-[subject_target]-(target)
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject)--(eventPrime)--(target)
WITH subject, subject_target, target, COLLECT(eventPrime)[0..200] AS eventList
UNWIND (CASE eventList WHEN [] THEN [null] else eventList end) as limitedEvents
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject)-[subject_event]-(limitedEvents)-[event_target]-(target)
RETURN subject, subject_target, target, subject_event, limitedEvents, event_target
```

Note: after the `SKIP...LIMIT...` I repeat the query only to identify the relationships between the nodes, in the sense that **a)** I'd like to have relationships in the json result; **b)** after quite a few attempts I can't manage to fetch relationships along with the first 3 `MATCH`s, specifically `COUNT(event)` doesn't work because each event is bidden with a relationship so that the count is constantly 1.

Comment: You have some ordering by eventCount occurring in the middle, so that complicates the approach for dealing with both targetViaEvent and directTarget in the same match. Also, you haven't given any details on the relationships in your matches, that information could be useful for devising a match that will match on both type of nodes at once, as well as whether the relationship types used are exclusive for these kinds of patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Given those requirements, I don't think we can construct a MATCH that will fulfill your conditions and match on both directTarget and targetViaEvent nodes at the same time in the same column. Until Neo4j or APOC procedures introduces some means of pulling results from separate matches into the same column (a UNION WITH would be perfect), adding the collections together is probably the best available approach.

Comment: @InverseFalcon yes it would be lovely to have UNION WITH! Does this implies the solution in your answer won't fulfill my requirements?

Comment: My answer should work with your requirements, and by building up the aggregations right after each separate match instead of trying to do both matches and aggregations at the same time you should see a fairly substantial performance improvement, but I'm unsure how well combining huge collections will scale with the number of targets in your graph. Hoping for good results, let us know how it works for you, or if this remains a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

We can improve your query a bit, as it stands now you're building up rows with each event + targetViaEvent in a cartesian product with every directTarget, so you're doing a ton of work you don't need to do. A good approach, especially with back-to-back MATCHes or OPTIONAL MATCHes where you want aggregations from both, is to build up your aggregations on each of them individually rather than trying to do them all at once. This avoids a cartesian product.

I'd suggest this as a replacement query:

```
MATCH (subject:Person {age:"38"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject)--(event:Event)--(targetViaEvent)
WITH subject, COUNT(event) AS eventCount, targetViaEvent
ORDER BY eventCount DESC
WITH subject, COLLECT(targetViaEvent) as eventTargets
// Above WITH means we now have only one row per subject so far
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject)--(directTarget)
  WHERE NOT directTarget:Event
WITH subject, COLLECT(directTarget) + eventTargets as targetList
UNWIND targetList AS target
WITH DISTINCT subject, target SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
...
```

EDIT

I just noticed a problem in your original query. In your two OPTIONAL MATCHes, you're sharing the 'subject' variable. That makes your second OPTIONAL MATCH dependent upon the `subjects` from your first OPTIONAL MATCH. It will not look for that pattern on :Persons who did not match your first OPTIONAL MATCH.

Basically, that set of OPTIONAL MATCHES should actually execute identically to if the first OPTIONAL MATCH was a MATCH instead.

If your intent was to run both OPTIONAL MATCHes on all :Persons, then you may have to change the first part of your query to this:

```
MATCH (subject:Person {age:"38"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject)--(event:Event)--(targetViaEvent)   
OPTIONAL MATCH (subject)--(directTarget) 
...
```

This may impact both your original query's speed and number of results built up.

Also, the result of both our queries (after you change yours) will also be returning rows of subjects without targets where both OPTIONAL MATCHes didn't match anything for a subject (in those cases, a single subject with a null target). If these aren't desired in the return, we'll both need to add `WHERE target IS NOT NULL` after the final WITH.

Comment: Appreciate for the quick response! I do meant to count `event` for each `targetViaEvent`, and sort `targetViaEvent` based on the count, which gives me **target with the most connected event** associated with each subject. I should've described detailly in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, looks like that approach will work fine.

Comment: I found it a bit tricky to assess the performance improvement of your code, since the execution time (from PROFILE result) varies from 2 sec to 8 sec, and sometimes even slower than my original Cypher. From the execution plan I can tell an `OptionalExpand(all)` step of `(subject)--(directTarget)` which causes 16,133 db hits right after node index seek of `Person`, is absent in your code. That's the only difference.

Comment: Right the reason that execution time varies may related to Query Plan Caching, as described in official knowledge base. I should've disable it before the benchmark.

Comment: I've added `dbms.query_cache_size=0` at the head of the `neo4j.conf`. In the `Server Configuration`result of Neo4j's Web UI I can see `dbms.query_cache_size`'s value is set to 0. However, as I execute the Cypher in your answer for multiple times, they still varies: `[5072, 3626, 3262, 3406, 4655, 4621, 3320, 5932, 2844, 3314, 6233]`(mean: 4207, median: 3626). On my Cypher in this question, the execution time goes: `[4076, 3538, 3160, 3579, 3095, 8468, 3939, 3545, 3551, 6680, 2583]`(mean: 4201, median: 3551). None of these made me convinced as if I disabled the query cache.

Comment: And it's hard to tell which Cypher overperforms.

Comment: Plus, I don't see any Cartisian product in the query plan, of my Cypher in the question, which  we'd usually see as in `PROFILE MATCH (n:LABEL0), (m:LABEL1) RETURN n, m`

Comment: I was mistaken, it won't be a true cartesian product. However, the rows built up at your first WITH will be, for each subject, each `targetViaEvent` paired with each `directTarget`, which is cartesian product with a more limited context. You should be able to check the number of rows built up. In your query, after the first WITH, end the query with `RETURN COUNT(*)`. On mine, use `RETURN COUNT(*)` after each WITH that follows an OPTIONAL MATCH.

Comment: As for the performance differences, or lack of them, either the data set is relatively small, or the planner is executing this in such a way that avoids (or eliminates the cost of) the building up of rows, or there's something I'm completely missing. It is tough to work without actual data, do you have a sample dataset you could add to the description, or link to the question?

Comment: I'm working on email relationships, the dataset is huge and a heavy load of work is needed to fully reproduce my case. If it is necessary, let me workout a minimal structure (yet with enough neighbor nodes to play with) to mimic my case, and get back to you then.

Comment: `RETURN COUNT(*)` results 139 rows after the first `WITH` in my query, while in yours, it results `1`s after the first and second `OPTIONAL MATCH...WITH...`, and jumps to 139 after `UNWIND...WITH...`.

Comment: I just spotted a possible problem in your original query, added details to my answer. Let me know how that changes things.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I found it yesterday that my query doesn't return anything if the first `MATCH` can't match any nodes.I changed exactly what you suggested to, and the results I posted above were based on this modified version: `MATCH...OPTIONAL MATCH...OPTIONAL MATCH...`

Comment: Also added `WHERE target IS NOT NULL` on both queries, and the execution time still varies. And both of the two caused almost the same db hits: 240104 and 240105. At this point I thought it might be helpful if I post my full query to the question.

Comment: This tip sped up my query performance significantly using multiple collect and distincts in coherence!